# Struggling to understand the second derivative

Tags: derivatives

I have mostly been using the derivative's limit definition, hence the second derivative and higher-order derivatives. However, today I came across this strange relation for the second derivative in one of the texts. Can someone help me understand how we got this relation for the second derivative on the right-hand side from the difference of the first derivatives on the left-hand side?
$$
\left.\frac{d T}{d x}\right|_{x+\frac{\Delta x}{2}}-\left.\frac{d T}{d x}\right|_{x-\frac{\Delta x}{2}} = \Delta x \frac{d^2T}{dx^2}
$$

Comment: This is not a definition of the second derivative. What text book are you reading?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the definition of the second derivative for sure, which I will change now. But, they used this relation without giving any context to it.

Comment: It is also not a valid equation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding $\Delta x$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: It helps to first understand that $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + \Delta x/2) - f(x - \Delta x/2)}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: @littleO Thank you very much. Got it :-)